# Select issue to count

Tags: sql, select

I have a problem that I don't know how to do.

I have tables joined and I need to get counts like how many emails one person has received in the last half of year.
Current code how I have selected outputs

```
SELECT 
account.EXT_STRING0 as client_ID,
account.EXT_STRING2 as Email,
activity.TEMPLATE_NAME as Template_name,
activity.NAME as campaign_name,
activity.EXECUTION_ID, -- unique campaign ID
activity.SEND_DATE,
Activity.OPEN_DATE,
Activity.CLICK_DATE
FROM  
    crmautomation.oocke1_account account 
Join 
    crmautomation.oocke1_activity activity 
    ON 
     (account.object_id = activity.rep_contact)
left JOIN 
    crmautomation.OBJ_VAL val1
       ON val1.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN_TYPE AND (val1.OBJ_VAL_ID in(4250950)) 
left JOIN 
    crmautomation.OBJ_VAL val2
       ON val2.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN_TYPE AND (val2.OBJ_VAL_ID in(4250951))
where activity.TEMPLATE_NAME= ('cabin_surprise_et')
and activity.SEND_DATE >('2015.12.01')
```

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfp4N.jpg)

Comment: You need commas between the select items, e.g `SELECT account.OBJECT_ID, account.OBJECT_ID...`

Comment: Thank you,
I did not notice that I was missing comas.
Br,
Melx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed commas in select statement, this is just sql syntax error

```
SELECT 
account.OBJECT_ID,
activity.TEMPLATE_NAME,
activity.SEND_DATE,
activity.OPEN_DATE,
activity.ACTIVITY_TYPE
From 
    crmautomation.oocke1_account account 
Join 
    crmautomation.oocke1_activity activity 
ON 
 (account.object_id = activity.rep_contact)
where Activity.ACTIVITY_TYPE is not NULL
```